# Find DIV by class under parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several DIV elements nested under a parent container. When the user clicks on one of these `cp-anchor`, I want to modify the CSS on a different one `cp-content`. I've tried dozens of methods found on Stack Overflow but for some reason it just doesn't seem to work as expected. Can anyone help point me in the correct direction?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9sk53zv/1/) of the example I am using.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $('.cp-anchor').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().find('cp-content').css('max-height','none');
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    </script>

<div class="cp-container">
    <div class="cp-content">
        <table id="tablepress-4">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="cp-anchor"><span class="cp-anchor-text">Show Full Contents</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in the fiddle. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Code mentioned in the question and fiddle is different , what's the exact issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `.` to signify a class selection.

```
//                     v
$(this).parent().find('.cp-content').css('max-height','none');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cp-anchor').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find('.cp-content').css('max-height', 'none');
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.cp-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cp-container">
  <div class="cp-content">
    CP CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="cp-anchor"><span class="cp-anchor-text">Show Full Contents</span></div>
</div>
```

---

Here's a vanilla JS version:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.cp-anchor')
          .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", showContent));

  function showContent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.parentNode.querySelector('.cp-content').style.maxHeight = 'none';
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.cp-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cp-container">
  <div class="cp-content">
    CP CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="cp-anchor"><span class="cp-anchor-text">Show Full Contents</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I have been starting at this for hours and completely missed that. Thank you so much for pointing out my stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

in Js use following one line of code:

```
$(this).parent().find('.cp-content').css('max-height','none');
```